# what does Spill mean in ARM ISA

Tags: arm64

I have write some test code, `just for testing the stack overflow`.

```
int MyFunc(long c)
{
    char buffer[12];
    return sprintf(buffer, "xxxxxxxxxxx%ld", c);
}
```

when I compile it to ARM64 assembly, I got the result

```
MyFunc(long): // @MyFunc(long)
  sub sp, sp, #32 // =32
  stp x29, x30, [sp, #16] // 16-byte Folded Spill
  add x29, sp, #16 // =16
  adrp x1, .L.str
  mov x2, x0
  add x1, x1, :lo12:.L.str
  add x0, sp, #4 // =4
  bl sprintf
  ldp x29, x30, [sp, #16] // 16-byte Folded Reload
  add sp, sp, #32 // =32
  ret
```

so, what does `16-byte Folded Spill` mean? and why?

Answer (score 9):

Stackoverflow.com is the perfect place for stack spill questions. =)

***`16-byte`*** is because we are saving two 8-byte registers to the stack.

***`Folded`*** for this one I am going to have to guess. Folding is when math operations are simplified combined. I going to go out on a whim and say it does not apply here and that it’s just a generic compiler message that only sometimes applies. If we had several of these in a row to save many registers to the stack and incremented the stack pointer(sp) just once then it would be combined because we would be using -32+16=-16 and this does not cause any extra math.

```
sub sp, sp, #32 
stp x27, x28, [sp] 
stp x29, x30, [sp, #16] <--- folded because we decrement sp once on 1st row
```

***`Spill`*** is the process of saving registers to memory because we need the extra registers. This is often referred to as spilling the registers to memory.